# How to make all rows in a table identical which the exception of 1 field?

Tags: sql, derby

I am trying to make it so all the users have the same items because I am doing an experiment with my app and need the experimental control of flattened data.

I used the following SQL statement in my last attempt:

```
insert into has (email,id,qty,price,item_info,image)  
select 'b@localhost.com',id,qty,price,item_info,image  
from 
(  
  select * from has  
  where email != 'b@localhost.com'  
) as o  
where o.id not in
(
 select id from has
 where email = 'b@localhost.com'
);
```

This should add all items which 'b@localhost.com' does not already have but other users do have, to 'b@localhost.com's inventory. (the 'has' table)

However, I get the following error:
**The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index**

I understand what this error means, but I do not understand why it is occurring.  My statement inserts all records which that email doesn't already have, so there should not be any duplicate id/email pairs.

The database structure is shown below, circles are attributes, squares are tables, and diamonds are relationship sets.  The HAS table is a relationship set on USER_ACCOUNT and ITEM, where the primary keys are email and id respectively.
[image]

Comment: To clarify, you want each user to have the same items as every other user?

Comment: Yes, and the items are represented by the  ' id ' attribute.

Comment: I am thinking my strategy is too complicated, that I should just copy everything into a temp table, then do 4 inserts for the 4 users.

Comment: What are the primary key fields in `has`?

Comment: HAS  is a relationship set, so its primary keys are the primary key's of the tables it connects. i.e:  'email' of USER_ACCOUNT and 'id' of ITEM.

Comment: Final try posted.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't know `derby` but you could try just changing to `select distinct 'b@localhost.com ...` . I think the issue is that multiple other users have same items that the target user does not.

Comment: Actually, since ID is the primary key field that won't be good enough. When the other users have the same item but with different QTY or other fields what values do you want for target user?

Comment: I've guessed that perhaps you don't really mind what those values are ... and my answer takes them from the has record with the `min` (alphabetically first) email address. If you do mind, let us know!

Comment: I ended up just manually moving items around until the users had the same items.   I only needed to do it once, so I figured it was forgivable to do that rather than toying with SQL commands for days.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
INSERT INTO has ( email,
                  id,
                  qty,
                  price,
                  item_info,
                  image )
SELECT a.email,
       b.id,
       a.qty,
       a.price,
       a.item_info,
       a.image
FROM has a
CROSS JOIN has b
JOIN
(
    SELECT email,
           id
    FROM has
) c ON a.email = c.email AND
       b.id <> c.id;
```

The `CROSS JOIN` appends a copy of each row of `has` to each row of `has`.  Please see http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php for more information on `CROSS JOIN`'s.

Each row of the resulting dataset will have two `id` fields, two `email` fields, two `qty` fields, etc.  By giving each instance of `has` an alias we create the fields `a.id`, `b.id`, `a.email`, etc.

We then compare each combination of "old" `email` address and "new" `id` to a list of existing `email` / `id` combinations and insert the old values with the new `id` replacing the old one into `has`

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php for more information on `CROSS JOIN`'s

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp for more information on `WHERE`'s `IN` operator

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp for more information on `GROUP BY`

Comment: I still get the same error, but thank you for trying.

Comment: I am not sure why its not working.  I still get the same error.  Its working for the first user I try it on, then on other ones it does not work.

Comment: I should  ask what is meant by a , b, c here?  are you implying the email should replace those parts?

Comment: Explanation on its way.

Comment: Maybe this is because I am using Derby, but I am getting syntax errors, (i was under the impression Derby basically was SQL).   its saying the comma's between some of the joins are incorrect syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141848/discussion-between-toonice-and-kiwicomb123).

Comment: Sorry your solution doesn't seem to work, my computer can't seem to handle it.

Comment: Well, at least we tried.  Thank you for the experience.  I suggest you switch to MySQL (my preference) or SQL-Server.

Comment: @toonice imho you shouldn't link w3school resources as their explanations show modest quality and sometimes parts of them are outright wrong ( as is the case with the `IN` operator and the cross join ).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is not that the code is trying to insert something which already exists, but that it's trying to insert more than one thing with the same PK. In lieu of an response to my comment, here is one way to get around the issue:

```
INSERT INTO has (email,id,qty,price,item_info,image)  
SELECT
    'b@localhost.com',
     source.id,
     source.qty,
     source.price,
     source.item_info,
     source.image  
FROM 
    (  
    SELECT email, id, qyt, price, item_info, image FROM has  
    ) as source
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT min(email) as min_email, id FROM has GROUP BY by id)
    ) as filter ON
     filter.min_email = source.email
WHERE
    source.id not in
    (
    SELECT id from has WHERE email = 'b@localhost.com'
    );
```

The key difference from your original code is my extra join to the subquery I've aliased as `filter`. This limits you to inserting the `has` details from a single `email` per `id`. There are other ways to do the same, but I figured that this would be a safe bet for being supported by Derby.

I removed the `WHERE` clause from the `source` sub-query as that is handled by the final `WHERE`.